# In Kotlin, can I access the known 'when' clause values?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have a few instances of this sort of code:

```
enum class Cat { Fat, Greedy, Sleepy, Lasagna }
...
when (cat) {
    Fat -> // do fat
    Greedy -> // do greedy
    else -> throw RuntimeException("You have a $cat cat - I don't know about those.")
}
```

I would like it to say "You have a $cat cat - I only know about Fat and Greedy" but I don't want to have to update the message when I add a new clause.

- Is there any way to read the options known by a 'when' clause? (I suspect not, but Kotlin is endlessly surprising.)

I don't want to decorate the enum with flags that need to be kept up to date with the when clause, nor add lambdas to the enum, to turn this when clause into dispatch-based logic.

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to set up an anti-pattern here. And "exhaustive" when cases are compile time only feature as far as I understand. You might do some ugly enum iteration in this simple case but if you consider a when case on a sealed class or interface then that logic immediately fails.

Comment: @Pawel you can use https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/sealed-subclasses.html

Comment: @k314159 still to collect all cases you have to perform ugly iteration (since classes that implements sealed interface or class can be abstract or open which propagate the cases) and then you have to mess with R8 to ensure your options are not wiped during minification. And even after that you have no info about options you do handle. If anything this looks like a solution that can be done with a preprocessor that actually does read your source code but writing one of those is a huge headache.

Comment: @Pawel You're quite right, this is a silly ugly question. It's only a message to make things nice for humans, and the enumeration involved isn't going to be subclassed or anything. The solution is an error condition, and doesn't even need to be particularly performant. I was intending this question in the jocular spirit of code golf: How can I avoid duplicating information and somehow extract the competence of the when clause at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can only work with equality-checking `when`s. It's not clear what you want to happen in cases like:

```
when (foo) {
    is Int -> { ... }
    is String -> { ... }
    in someList -> { ... }
    else -> // what values would "the options known by a 'when'" be?
}
```

To actually do this with `when`, you would need some sort of annotation processing to look at the `when` expression, and generate a list of the bound values. There is no language feature to do this.

I would recommend just writing your own kind of `when`. A simple implementation would be:

```
fun <T, R> `when`(target: T, vararg clauses: Pair<T, () -> R>, `else`: (Set<T>) -> R) {
    (clauses.firstOrNull { it == target }?.second?.invoke()) ?:
        `else`(clauses.map { it.first }.toSet())
}
```

```
`when` (cat,
    Fat to {},
    Greedy to {},
    `else` = { boundValues ->
        throw RuntimeException("You have a $cat cat - I only know about ${ boundValues.joinToString { it.toString() } }.")
    }
)
```

---

Of course, you can make this look more similar to the actual `when` by using the [DSL builder](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html) pattern. For example, here I implemented one that supports putting multiple values in one clause.

```
data class WhenClause<T, R>(val matchedValues: List<T>, val action: () -> R) {
    fun evaluate(value: T): R? =
        action.takeIf { value in matchedValues }?.invoke()
}

class WhenContext<T, R> {
    private val clauses = mutableListOf<WhenClause<T, R>>()

    private var `else`: ((Set<T>) -> R)? = null

    fun evaluate(value: T) =
        clauses.firstNotNullOfOrNull { it.evaluate(value) } ?:
            `else`?.invoke(clauses.flatMap { it.matchedValues }.toSet()) ?:
            error("Not exhaustive")

    infix fun T.then(block: () -> R) {
        clauses.add(WhenClause(listOf(this), block))
    }
    
    infix fun T.or(other: T) = listOf(this, other)
    infix fun List<T>.or(other: T) = plusElement(other)

    infix fun List<T>.then(block: () -> R) {
        clauses.add(WhenClause(this, block))
    }

    fun `else`(block: (Set<T>) -> R) {
        this.`else` = block
    }
}

inline fun <T, R> `when`(value: T, block: WhenContext<T, R>.() -> R): R {
    val context = WhenContext<T, R>()
    context.block()
    return context.evaluate(value)
}
```

Example usage:

```
`when` (cat) {
    (Fat or Greedy) then { }
    `else` { boundValues ->
        throw RuntimeException("You have a $cat cat - I only know about ${ boundValues.joinToString { it.toString() } }.")
    }
}
```

Comment: I only wanted the equality-checking when case. I think I have to award you the green tick. I was torn though - this is a lot more code than I had in mind, but it's elegant, works with more than just enums, and I like the 'or' and that it preserves return values. I will have to rename the method names though - I really hate quoted identifiers... although I suppose I could pretend those are sarcastic or air quotes, maybe.

Comment: Actually, I take overengineered and 'more code' back - the first version is concise and fits exactly - sorry, I was in a rush to get home.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do it "properly", but you might be able to do a sneaky devilish hack. You probably shouldn't actually implement this; it's just a wild idea.

If the function containing the `when` clause is side-effect-free:

```
when (cat) {
    ...
    else -> {
        knownCats = Cat.entries.filter { cat ->
            try {
                currentFunction(cat)
                true
            } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
                false
            }
        }
        throw RuntimeException("You have a $cat cat - I only know about $knownCats.")
    }
```

You'll have to find a way to avoid endless recursion, but you get the idea.

Comment: Haha, nice. I'm really sorry - I would love to award you the green tick because it's a beautifully hacky and self-contained/minimal solution to my stupid problem, but I only have one green tick and @Sweeper's is not only hilariously over-engineered but it also leaves the return type alone. I'm going to have to rename those quoted method names though - I don't like the quotes. I definitely will be pursuing your route for a while though: I think abusing the class of the thrown exceptions might be a nice avenue.